# Align text to the right and center vertically, xamarin android textview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to align the text of my TextView to right and to be centered vertically in the view. I've tried different combinations of gravity and textAligment attributes but I've only been able to center the the text vertically and it's still aligned to the left of the view.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3846"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#cfd8dc"     
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `gravity` to `center_vertical|right` and remove your `textAlignment` tag:

```
<TextView
    android:text="stackoverflow"
    android:id="@+id/textViewInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3846"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:background="#cfd8dc"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```